# Running total in Python reset when met a threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to calculate a running total that reset to 0 when it reaches a certain threshold. I'm pretty new to python and gave it a shot. I feel like i'm on the right track, but could use a little help. Any pointers / solutions are greatly appreciated.

```
Sample Data

Date        Team    Amount  Threshold

1/9/2020    Team1   364970  5000000

7/18/2020   Team2   762532  5000000

6/15/2020   Team1   497686  5000000

3/14/2020   Team2   762980  5000000

2/14/2020   Team2   793256  5000000
```

1. I need to calculate the running total sorting an unsorted dataset by Team & Date asc
2. When the cumulative sum is greater than the Threshold, have it reset to 0 and continue calculating the sum again until it meets the threshold again.
3. Threshold is static it shouldn't be aggregated

```
my attempt:
df = sheets.get_cells(sheet, ws, has_col_header = True)

df["Amount"]  = df["Amount"].astype(int)

df['Running Total'] = df.groupby('Team').cumsum().astype(int)

df["Threshold"]  = df["Threshold"].astype(int)

df = df.sort_values(by=['Team','Date'])

df.groupby('Team').apply(lambda x: (x['Amount'].cumsum() *(x['Budget'] > x['Running Total'].astype(int)).shift(-1)).fillna(x['Running Total']))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this and see if it's what you're looking for.

```
thresh = 5000000
df['cs'] = df.groupby((df['Amount'].cumsum()) // thresh)['Amount'].cumsum()
```

If you need to groupby `Team`, then:

```
df['cs'] = df.groupby(['Team', df.groupby('Team')['Amount'].cumsum() // thresh])['Amount'].cumsum()
```

Comment: +1 , I think the OP also wants to group by team though.  `df1['cs'] = df1.groupby(['Team',((df1['Amount'].cumsum()) // thresh)])['Amount'].cumsum()`

Comment: If OP wants to group by team, would he have to do two groupby's (I am unsure if groupby will perform the Teams groupby first, and then the cumsum, or if they are done at the same time.)

Comment: `df['cs'] = df.groupby('Team')['Amount'].cumsum() // thresh`
`df['cs'] = df.groupby(['Team','cs'])['Amount'].cumsum()`

Comment: `df['cs'] = df.groupby(['Team', df.groupby('Team')['Amount'].cumsum() // thresh])['Amount'].cumsum()`  that is how you could do it to make it a one-liner, but perhaps yours is more readable.

Comment: Boom! thanks everyone, was able to get it from your answers, I appreciate it! have a good weekend.